# Can I write an OpenGL application without binding it to a certain windowing library?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glfw

As I mentioned in a question before, I am trying to make a simple game engine in `C++` with `OpenGL`.

I am currently using `GLFW` for drawing the `OpenGL` context and I chose it because I heard it's one of the faster ones out there. However, it doesn't support widgets and I really don't want to write them myself. So I decided to get into Qt a bit, because it would allow me to have a pane for the render context and different handy bars as well as all the fancy elements for editing a world map, setting `OpenGL` rules, etc.

I want to use `GLFW` on the exported version of that game, though. **Is that possible without an abstraction layer of some kind?**

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be possible: you can have a GUI in Qt and launch glfw contexts in parallel whenever you need them. Whether you would need some abstraction layer or not depends on what exactly you want to do, what kind of interaction do you want between the Qt-specific and the glfw-specific parts, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possibile, infact I'm writing a 3D engine that is not coupled to any windowing library and can be used with Qt, SDL or whatever.

You of course have just to wrap regular GL calls into a higher level layer, this require you don't call "SwapBuffers" inside your GL code.

If by abstraction layer you mean "inversion of control" so, you don't want to override a "Render/Update" method that's exactly what I done. If by "abstraction layer" you mean you want to use GL directly than it is still possible.

Basically every windowing system have "some place" where you can make your GL calls (between MakeCurrent and SwapBuffers). Just read documentation of your windowing system.

Comment: Will Accept as answer in a few minutes :) Thanks really much!